Relation between energy of cosmic inflation and dark energy
Searching for "relation between inflation and dark energy" I found: "The energy scale of inflation is possibly 10^24eV, while the energy scale of dark energy is around 10^-3eV."
e.g. here: https://supernova.lbl.gov/~evlinder/defaq.html or at en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflation_(cosmology), both without citation.
I am a little bit puzzled about the units since I've seen dark energy only given as energy density but most of all I'd like to have the original source / article for that. Or is it trivial / common knowledge?

In particle physics units with $\hbar=c=1$, mass has the same units as energy which has the same units as inverse length. So an energy density has the same units as energy to the fourth power. So taking the one-fourth power of the cosmological constant energy density (in particle physics units) gives you the energy scale being described in your source.

Related: What is the energy density of the inflaton field?
